# SQL Order By NEWID in a CASE statement

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to involve NEWID() (so I can return the results in a random order) in a CASE statement with in the ORDER BY clause, like so:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @RankingMethod = 1 THEN intFoo ELSE NEWID() END DESC
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as it throws "Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int"

Is there a way to construct this ORDER BY to have it either sort randomly or by a specified column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @RankingMethod = 1 THEN intFoo ELSE -1 END DESC, newid()
```

If needed, choose another "magic value" instead of `-1`